# How can I regex case insensitive in unicode string?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch

Lets say I want to search for the Greek work `Καλημέρα` which means good morning
How do I search for `ΚΑΛΗΜΕΡΑ` or `καλημέρα` or even `κΑΛΗΜερα`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example using `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` items 1 & 3 match as do items 2 & 4:

```
NSString *morningList = @" Καλημέρα, ΚΑΛΗΜΕΡΑ, καλημέρα, κΑΛΗΜερα";
NSArray *morningTests = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Καλημέρα", @"ΚΑΛΗΜΕΡΑ", @"καλημέρα", @"κΑΛΗΜερα", nil];

for (NSString *morning in morningTests) {
    NSRange range = [morningList rangeOfString:morning options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSLog(@"location of '%@': %lu", morning, range.location);
}
```

NSLog output:

```
location of 'Καλημέρα': 1
location of 'ΚΑΛΗΜΕΡΑ': 11
location of 'καλημέρα': 1
location of 'κΑΛΗΜερα': 11
```

Not exactly what was asked but perhaps helpful.